# Where can I find a Ralts in Pokemon X?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I was wondering where I could find a Ralts in Pokemon X. Does anyone know where I should go? I want a Gardevior for my endgame team.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in [Route4](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kalos_Route_4):
[image]

both in red and yellow flowers, with a chance of only 5%, so it's quite rare
[image]

You can also find Kirlia in a Fairy type [Friend Safari](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friend_Safari#Fairy-type_Safari).